# how to replace via regex with group enclosed in python

Tags: python

Here's the scenario:

```
import re

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = "s = \"456\";"
    ss = re.sub(r'(.*s\s+=\s+").*?(".*)', r"\1123\2", s)
    print ss
```

What I intend to do is to replace '456' with 123, but the result is 'J3";'. I try to `print '\112'`, it turns out to be character 'J'. Thus, is there any method to specify that \1 is the group in regex, not something like a escape character in Python? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `\1` to `\g<1>`

```
>>> re.sub(r'(.*s\s+=\s+").*?(".*)', r"\g<1>123\2", s)
's = "123";'
```

If there was no numbers present next to the backreference (*like \1,\2*), you may use `\1` or `\2` but if you want to put a number next to `\1` like `\11`, it would give you  a garbage value . In-order to differntiate between the backreferences and the numbers, you should use `\g<num>` as backrefernce where `num` refers the capturing group index number.

Comment: Thanks! it works. Could you plz paste the document URL relevant to this topic, so I could get an overall comprehension of it.

Comment: @Judking: The Python regex howto (in the core docs) is probably your best start: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html